# select data from previous row as current row data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following select in my mysql database:

```
select t.col1, t.THE_DATE, (select ?? as PREVIOUS_DATE) 
from DUMMY_TABLE t 
order by date
```

What I am trying to achieve is have the 'PREVIOUS_DATE' contain the value of the previous row's 'THE_DATE' column if there is one.

So if DUMMY_TABLE has the data :

```
col1 THE_DATE 
x     10-01-2010
x     10-01-2012
x     10-01-2009
```

my select should return

```
col1  THE_DATE   PREVIOUS_DATE
x    10-01-2009       
x    10-01-2010   10-01-2009
x    10-01-2012   10-01-2010
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a loop and not a plain select? Could be better to avoid multiple results in the subquery. Unless you have an unique id

Comment: @KESO - A loop is almost never better than a query.

Comment: @MatBailie of course not, but if the problem is not performance, it can be another idea

Comment: If you're using the latest version of MySQL, you can use [LAG window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `order by` clause in `subquery` with `limit` clause :

```
select t.col1, t.the_date, 
      ( select t1.the_date 
        from dummy_table t1
        where t1.col = t.col and
              t1.the_date < t.the_date
        order by t1.the_date desc
        limit 1
      ) as PREVIOUS_DATE 
from dummy_table t 
order by the_date;
```

Comment: Is this OK if there are duplicate dates?

Comment: @ChrisLear That depends on what you want to happen.  If you have the sequence `0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4` and you ask for the previous numbers you get `NULL, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3`.   **Both** the `2`'s think the immediately preceding value is `1`.  Is that okay?   Well, that's for ***you*** to define.

Comment: @MatBailie that's why I asked. But it's actually for the original poster to decide, not me. I was only pointing out a possible issue, which might not be obvious at first glance. The reason I made it a question (rather than saying "this doesn't work for duplicate dates", say) is that the answer might be a matter of taste.

Comment: @ChrisLear - Apologies, I assumed you were the OP.  Please forgive me, I was born stupid.